# Question about period of time when bird lands on transmission line

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, voltage

I know this topic has been asked alot, but I'd still like to ask a question to clear possible misunderstandings I have about the period of time before the bird physically lands on the wire, because I've seen some (I think) terrible answers and some good ones and I'd like to clear up any misunderstandings.

**My understanding is as follows**: The transmission wire is at some large voltage. When a bird, coming from ground level, comes close enough to the wire then the electric field becomes strong enough at some point on the bird's trajectory that the air breaks down between the two to equalize their potential. But that current is not [long/strong](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158778/can-a-bird-previously-at-earth-potential-get-electrocuted-by-landing-on-a-powe) (answer by Mister Mystère) enough for the bird to get significantly hurt until they're at equal potential because the bird is not some massive body like the earth so it doesnt take long to equalize. Unlike this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6g0cDuQXGs&t=55s) where what I'm assuming they're doing is safely equalizing the potential between helicopter/human and wire and it looks like it takes quite some time.

The main point of confusion is an upvoted answer in the same [thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158778/can-a-bird-previously-at-earth-potential-get-electrocuted-by-landing-on-a-powe) by a very high valued user Andy Aka saying something like the bird's potential continuosly changes from ground to wire, which is just terribly wrong, isn't it? If that were the case the air would never break down, and in his picture the bird which would be at $0$ potential is completely absent which would change the field lines dramatically in the vicinity bird/wire.

**QUESTION** Is my understanding of that situation correct or is the answer given in the thread i linked correct that there is some kind of continuous change of potential of the bird even though the air is not conductive really at all?

Comment: I edited the question to be more focused, I hope that's enough.